# Naming convention for service application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Want to know the Microsoft recommendation of naming conventions for Service Applications.

Comment: List of service apps 2013. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12512.sharepoint-2013-service-applications-list.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their is no recommendation on the Naming Convention on the Service application. Naming conventions are obviously important to SharePoint farms.  Having a naming convention drastically improves efficiency related to configuration tasks, troubleshooting, documentation, and knowledge transfer.

What We design our farm, we keep these things in mind for naming.

- Farm Name
- Farm type i.e Prod, Test, QA, Dev
- SharePoint Version.
- Service Application name( some time use the short name, i.e Excel services ECS).
- If multiple Instance of Service App(usually for MMS), then use the WebApp / customer name.

So here is Service Application name

- Excel Services: Prod-ECS-2013
- Managed Metadata Services: Prod-MMS-2013-WebAppName

http://njbblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/naming-convention-for-sharepoint.html

[Some Community Best Practice](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12438.community-best-practices-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There is no naming convention as such.

The most straightforward way to name service applications is to use the same name as the service application type. You can see the names of the different service application types in the “New” dropdown button on Manage Service Applications in Central Administration.

If more than one service application exists, just add a dash and an additional value that differentiates the service application.

Examples:

- Excel Services Application
- Managed Metadata Service
- Secure Store Service

Examples with more than one service application of the same type:

Corporate level: Managed Metadata Service
Department level: Managed Metadata Service – Sales Department

https://christoffervonsabsay.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/naming-conventions-for-sharepoint-2010-environments/